# Use Swashbuckle to get one OpenAPI document from multiple .NET Core projects

Tags: .net-core, swashbuckle, openapi

Is there a way to get a single OpenAPI document containing all operations from multiple .NET core projects using Swashbuckle?

Context:

We have multiple frontdoor projects (built with .NET Core) but they are semantically a part of one service, for which we want to have a single OpenAPI document. Since Swashbuckle generates the document at start up for each individual project, we end up with multiple OpenAPI documents.

Is there a workaround to get these operations to show up under one document? From the way Swashbuckle works, it seems like this would not be possible? We can probably combine the Swagger documents later on with other libraries, but if Swashbuckle has a way to support this, we would prefer that.

Comment: It seems like you need sometime similar to Azure API Management's  developer portal.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to use an `api gateway`.

Actually there are multiple commercial product that offer this service, like:

> - [Apigee](https://cloud.google.com/apigee/)
> - [AWS API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/)
> - [Azure API Management](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/api-management/)

but if you don't want to use (and pay) for these services, you can use an open source alternative for .Net Core like **[Ocelot](https://github.com/ThreeMammals/Ocelot)**

With API Gateway you'll be able to merge multiple api project, and menage their use and distribution (eg. security policy, throttling, etc..).